# Blender 3 video editing can't cut from start

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I am attempting to remove a few minutes from a beginning of a video. I am doing it the most primitive straightforward way, as found in all the tutorials, etc.

Is this a bug or am I doing something terribly wrong.

1. Drop video to timeline
2. Navigate to e.g. 70 seconds from start
3. Split (k)
4. Delete clip before split
5. Playback - set start
6. Navigate to e.g. 120 seconds after start, playback - set end

Now, "first frame of playback and rendering range" reads e.g. 2060 (not exact) last one 3450 (not exact)
In render properties, Frame Range reads same numbers.

Playback preview plays stuff from the correct start/end.

BUT, for some reason and very frustrating, when I render this, my rendered video starts from the original beginning. To add insult to the injury, audio of the resulting render is correctly starting from the cut.
What's going on?

Blender version: 3.0.1

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the sequencer after all operations? I am not familiar with the operator “Playback - Set Start.”

Comment: try using SHIFT-K for split

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have only [Preview Range](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/graph_editor/introduction.html#graph-preview-range) ... check "stopwatch" icon on right side of Timeline's Editor header.

When enabled it is temporarily set for preview not render.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Confirming that cutting a new start works as you intend in 3.1.

I dropped a video into the timeline. Navigated into the clip. Split, deleted before split.
[image: Blender 3.1. 1GB video clip dropped onto Timeline]

Set new range for `Preview` and for `Render.` Playback and render output both have new start.

I used `View` ... `Range` ... `Set Frame Range to Strips.`The same will work from `Frame Range`. [vklidu's answer about `Preview`](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/253444/90622) is also correct for multiple Blender versions.

[image: New start time -- Frame 267]

Answer (score -1):

You want to enable the <kbd>K</kbd> key for splitting strips?

Go to *Marker > Add Marker*, and you're good to go!